# Eloquent ORM query to return only models that have specific models in their collections

Tags: database, orm, eloquent

I am struggling to get Eloquent ORM to produce the results I need.  I have three models, Job, Phase and Team.

The Job Model

```
public function phases()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Eloquent\Models\Phase', 'job_id', 'job_id');
}
```

The Phase Model

```
public function job()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Eloquent\Models\Job', 'job_id', 'job_id');
}

public function teams()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Eloquent\Models\Team', 'phase_id', 'phase_id');
}
```

The Team Model

```
public function phase()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Eloquent\Models\Phase', 'phase_id', 'phase_id');
}
```

When I execute the query

```
$query = Eloquent\Models\Job::with("Phases.Teams");
$result = $query->get();
```

I get 40 jobs, which include 50 phases and 75 teams.  All Good.

When I execute the query

```
$query = Eloquent\Models\Job::with(array("Phases.Teams" => function($query)
{
    $query->whereRaw("teams.team_member_quota > 5");
}));
```

I get a collection with 40 jobs, which include 50 phases and 20 teams.  It seems I still get all of the Jobs and Phases, but only the teams have been filtered.

I would like to get a collection of only Jobs that have a team with a team_member_quota > 5, and have within them only Phases that have a team with a team_member_quota > 5, as well as with Phases only have Teams with a team_member_quota > 5.

Is this possible with Eloquent ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indeed limits the jobs to only jobs that contain teams whose team_member_quota > 5

```
$query = Eloquent\Models\Job::whereHas('phases', function($query)
{
    $query->whereHas('teams', function ($q) 
    {
        $q->whereRaw("teams.team_member_quota > 5");
    });
});
```

However, adding the "with" clause

```
$query->with('phases.teams');
```

still brings back all the phases for each of those jobs, whether, they contain teams that meet the criteria or not, and all the teams within those phases, whether they have a team_member_quota > 5 or not.

I found this "with" clause worked

```
$query->with(array(
    "phases" => function($q1)
    {
        $q1->whereHas('teams', function($q2)
        {
            $q2->whereRaw('teams.team_member_quota > 5');
        });
    },
    "phases.teams" => function($q)
    {
        $q->whereRaw("teams.team_member_quota > 5");
    }
));
```

providing only the phases that contain teams that meet the criteria, and teams that meet the criteria within the results.

Answer (score 0):

You need `whereHas` for this, but since it doesn't work with nested relations, you need to nest it manually:

```
$query = Eloquent\Models\Job::whereHas('phases', function($query)
{
    $query->whereHas('teams', function ($q) {
        $q->whereRaw("teams.team_member_quota > 5");
    });
})
// ->with('phases.teams') // if you still need to load all the relations
;
```

This will fetch `Jobs` that have related `Phases` having `Teams` with > 5 members (and load all the related models for those jobs as well if you need)

---

Or define another `hasManyThrough` relation:

```
// Job model
public function teams()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('Team', 'Phase');
}

// then:
$query = Eloquent\Models\Job::whereHas('teams', function ($q) {
        $q->whereRaw("teams.team_member_quota > 5");
});
```

For `hasManyThrough` you need to make sure that all the models have `$primaryKey` defined, for it seems you don't use default `id`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer does limit the jobs to those that contain teams whose team_member_quota > 5.  However, adding the simple with('phases.teams') caused ALL of the phases and teams within those jobs to be returned.  However, your answer did lead me down the road to getting the correct result, so many thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course, that's what you asked for. If you need to limit also loaded teams to be limited, simply add that code you had before in the `with` method. And if you need to load only teams, without phases, then use `with(['teams' => function($q) ...`